# Serialize json mandrill api with template

Tags: json, mandrill

I'm trying to get an email off using mandrill and my app. I am trying to serialise the json object into an array before it goes out - but I get a response back from mandrill with the following

```
{
   "status":"error",
   "code":-2,
   "name":"ValidationError",
   "message":"Validation error: {\"template_content\":[\"Please enter an array\"]}"
}
```

Any ideas, the template name is the template-slug I have used in mandrill and the template_content is in array.

```
key=myKey&
template_name=template-name&
template_content[name]=Name of Content&
template_content[content]=Mass Emails&
message[html]=<p align="left">I have a lot of text here</p>
message[subject]=«SUBJECT»&
message[from_email]=«SENDEREMAIL»&
message[from_name]=«SENDERNAME»&
message[to][0][email]=«RECIPIENTEMAIL»&
message[to][0][name]=«RECIPIENTNAME»&
message[to][0][type]=to&
async=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I over looked that the template_content needed to be in an array so this works now

```
key=myKey&
template_name=template-name&
template_content[name][0]=Name of Content&
template_content[content][0]=Mass Emails&
message[html]=<p align="left">I have a lot of text here</p>
message[subject]=«SUBJECT»&
message[from_email]=«SENDEREMAIL»&
message[from_name]=«SENDERNAME»&
message[to][0][email]=«RECIPIENTEMAIL»&
message[to][0][name]=«RECIPIENTNAME»&
message[to][0][type]=to&
async=true
```